# How to fix AttributeError: "NoneType" object has no attribute "encode" using smtplib

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to make a script to allow a user to send the contents of a file via gmail.

This is is my code:

```
if input1 == 'mail':
    path = input("open -- ")
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        addr = os.environ.get("email")
        pw = os.environ.get("pass")
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(addr, pw)
        reading = file.read()
        subject = path
        body = reading
        msg = f'Subject {subject}\n\n{body}'
        input3 = ('recipient -- ')
        server.sendmail(email, input3, msg)'
```

and it's giving me this error:

```
  File "C:/Users/Whit/PycharmProjects/rps/venv/Scripts/maxnum.py", line 36, in <module>
    server.login(addr, pw)
  File "C:\Users\Whit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 721, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "C:\Users\Whit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 638, in auth
    authobject(challenge).encode('ascii'), eol='')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Answer (score 2):

This usually occurs when you create the environment variables but forget to restart your editor. So a simple restart should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `server.login(addr, pw)`, but getting `addr` and `pw` through environment variables. It seems you have not actually passed them like that.

Answer (score 0):

Some value you provided to `smtplib` is `None`. Most likely is I'd the result of one or both of the calls to `getent`.

What is your program expected to do if `email` or `pass` environment variables are not set? You should probably  check the result of `getent` before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your environment variable is there — if not, add it back because if there’s none, it returns

```
None
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31327737)