# nonetype error when securing passwords in environment variables in windows 11

Tags: python, environment-variables, web-development-server, visual-web-developer, secure-coding

2023-10-17 00:21:31.357 Uncaught app exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\pythonProject\portfolio\send_email.py", line 21, in send_email
server.login(username, password)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 739, in login
(code, resp) = self.auth(
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 652, in auth
authobject(challenge).encode('ascii'), eol='')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 541, in _run_script
exec(code, module.**dict**)
File "D:\pythonProject\portfolio\pages\Contact Us.py", line 17, in 
send_email(message)
File "D:\pythonProject\portfolio\send_email.py", line 20, in send_email
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host, port, context=context) as server:
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 284, in **exit**
raise SMTPResponseException(code, message)
smtplib.SMTPResponseException: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Lear
n more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials ja10-20020a170902efca00b001c62e3e1286sm8861643plb.166 - gsmtp')

```
import smtplib, ssl
from dotenv import load_dotenv   #for python-dotenv method
import os

from pathlib import Path  
env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)


def send_email(message):
    host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    port = 465

    username = "nityaoberoi09@gmail.com"
    password = os.environ.get("pswrd")

    receiver = "nityaoberoi09@gmail.com"
    context = ssl.create_default_context()

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host, port, context=context) as server:
        server.login(username, password)
        server.sendmail(username, receiver, message)
```

I used this code to send mail in my program and created a environment variable to secure my password in it from control panel > System and Security > System > Advanced system Settings>Environment Variables
but it is showing that the password as not accepted when i used os.environ.get("pswrd") in python console it is also showing none

Comment: `pswrd` is not set in your environment, so `os.environ.get("pswrd")` returns None.  This is probably because your code is looking in **the current directory** for the `.env` file, which is **not necessarily** the same directory as the python script itself.

Comment: You can use this code to see the actual current directory `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AttributeError%3A+%27NoneType%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27encode%27, plenty of similar questions there. Please also make sure you include a [mcve] in your Q. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Your question could take a bit of editing to be easier to read: this is what I did, this is the code, this is the error. Look here for an example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59003664/how-to-fix-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-encode-using-smt
Note that the above example looks similar to your query